# Undefined variable $credentials, tried several solutions but couldn't understand my mistake

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner, learning Laravel. I was trying to create a web page which will show me my login Info(like email and password) once I log in. In my controller part I passed values using route parameter, but when I call it in blade, it shows

ErrorException
Undefined variable $credentials (View: .....\new project\NewLearn\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

My database has users table( email and password columns (which will be shown only), along with name,id, timestamps).

my LoginController

```
public function loginProcess(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:4',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->except(['_token']);
        if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->route('welcome', [$credentials->email]);
        }
        else{
        $this->setErrorMessage('Invalid!');
        return redirect()->back();
        }
```

my routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('login');});

Route::view('/welcome', 'welcome')->middleware('auth')->name('welcome');
Route::post('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'loginProcess'])->middleware('guest')->name('login');
Route::get('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class, 'loginProcess'])->middleware('guest');
```

my welcome.blade.php

```
         @extends('master')
         @section('contents')
             @include('partials.jumbotron')
         @stop
         @section('content')

        <h3 class="pb-3 mb-4 font-italic border-bottom">
            {{$credentials->email}}
        </h3>

        <div class="blog-post">
            <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>

        </div>

        <nav class="blog-pagination">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Older</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary disabled" href="#">Newer</a>
        </nav>


         @stop
```

Where am I making the mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views) shows how to ... pass data to views

Comment: @brombeer I tried that too by using-   return view('welcome', $credentials); .... same error happens

Comment: That would be `return view('welcome', ['credentials' => $credentials]);`

Comment: Yes, done that too. But my blade still not getting any value.

Comment: So in your blade, check if it _is_ set and only display it then. Might be your view is called from your route without the credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it pretty hard on yourself.
Let us start by changing

```
Route::view('/welcome', 'welcome')->middleware('auth')->name('welcome');
```

to

```
Route::get('/welcome', function() {
   $user = auth()->user();
   return view('welcome', compact('user'));
})->middleware('auth')->name('welcome');
```

Now in login process simply change

```
if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->route('welcome', [$credentials->email]);
        }
```

to

```
if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->route('welcome');
        }
```

Now inside your blade file you can simple use

```
{{ $user->email }}
```

Comment: Since you are a beginner in laravel and learning, it is important to learn in the right direction. I would like to suggest you to visit https://laracasts.com and thoroughly start https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch. It will build solid foundation for your future.

Comment: Okay, I'll complete it. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You already pass `$credentials->email` from controller. If you want to keep your blade (view) file you can just pass `$credentials` from controller and return view with parameters instead of route redirect.

Something like this:

```
return view('welcome', [
    'credentials' => $credentials,
])
```

Comment: Yes, I did it too but it shows the same error, Undefined Variable. Maybe I'm not being able to call the passed value in blade? I'm calling it like {{ $credentials}}. Should I use any loop or something since $credentials has both email and password value?

Comment: Can you `@dd($credentials)` in your blade file and see if there anything there?

Comment: Yes, I did that in controller and controller shows value. But when used in blade, it shows same Undefine Variable error :(

Comment: did you pass just `$credentials` instead of `$credentials->email`?

Comment: yes, I tried both `$credentials`,`$credentials->email` .... as my table is user I even tried a different variable `$data= User::all();`.
`return view('welcome', $data);` . but it gives the same error when I type {{$data}}/{{$data->email}}.

Comment: But you must pass as I wrote in my ansswer ['credentials' => $credentials]

Comment: Can you vote for my answer if everything is ok now?

Comment: I can't vote as I don't have reputation, but I still gave the feedback and I'll vote it again when I'll have enough reputation, thanks a lot :)